# gdaldem output file size explodes

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, srtm, file-size

I want to create a color-relief and a hillshade with gdaldem and use them with mapnik. System: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server, gdal-bin 1.10.

Here are my steps:

- Download all SRTM tiles from viewfinderpanoramas:

  `wget -r -np -l 1 -A zip http://viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm`
- Unpack all zip files
- Fill all remaining voids (creates out of every .hgt a .hgt.tif file)

  `for hgtfile in *.hgt;do gdal_fillnodata.py $hgtfile $hgtfile.tif; done`
- Merge all .tifs into one huge tif. This file will is the raw DEM with full resolution and the start for any further steps:

  `gdal_merge.py -n 32767 -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -o ../raw.tif *.hgt.tif`
- Convert the raw file into Mercator projection, interpolate and shrink e.g. to 1 km/pixel:

  `gdalwarp -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -t_srs "+proj=merc +ellps=sphere +R=6378137 +a=6378137 +units=m" -r bilinear -tr 1000 1000 raw.tif warp-1000.tif`
- Create color-relief with transparency (alpha channel) and lzw compression:

  `gdaldem color-relief -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 -alpha warp-1000.tif relief.txt relief-1000.tif`
- Create hillshade

  `gdaldem hillshade -z 7 -compute_edges -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=JPEG warp-1000.tif hillshade-1000.tif`

I get these output file sizes:

`warp-5000.tif: 113 MB
warp-1000.tif: 606 MB
warp-500.tif: 1.7 GB`

`relief-5000.tif: 17 MB
relief-1000.tif: 19 MB
relief-500.tif: >60 GB` (hdd was full!)

`hillshade-5000.tif: 2.7 MB
hillshade-1000.tif: 75 MB
hillshade-500.tif: >70 GB` (hdd was full!)

Why does the file size suddenly explode?

Comment: Shading and compressing in the same operation might be a bit difficult. Note, just because an image is compressed doesn't mean that it's smaller file size; try uncompressed and then gdal_translate to compress, but first get yourself a new hard drive - if you've only got 60GB free space the file allocation is working overtime to place data unless your drive is < 300GB total... even then, you need more free space to do this - hard drives are cheap, time is expensive.

Comment: Sorry, my hard drive is 1 TB. I just had several tries with the SRTM tiles and my mapnik server and database consume 500 GB. Creating once uncompressed, compressing with gdal_translate and then deleting the uncompressed file, could work. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compression doesn't work well in the process of generating a new file with "tiled=yes" or above a certain file size. I solved this problem as supposed by Michael:

Create your hillshade by compressing it with lossless LZW. In my example, the whole planet warped with 500 meter resolution, the hillshade-500.tif consumes 131 GB.

```
gdaldem hillshade -z 4 -compute_edges -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co PREDICTOR=2 warp-500.tif hillshade-500.tif
```

Then compress it with lossy JPEG:

```
gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co TILED=YES hillshade-500.tif hillshade-500-comp.tif
```

The resulting file size is quite as expected:

`hillshade-500.tif: 131 GB`

`hillshade-500-comp.tif: 249 MB` (= 1,9%)

So you first need enough disk space, but then can compress the file further.

Note: Add `-co bigtiff=yes` only if your file size exceeds 4 GB.